# Redis hotspot concerning client requests

Tags: redis

I want to avoid hot spot only in case of client requests. What criteria should I take into account? 
Some papers define this threshold in 500 QPS (read) but i want something that based on some metrics in a real scenario. In my case when client request reach a threshold on a master node, i migrate the keys to other master (that do not exceed this threshold) and redirect the client there and the number of requests.

Can i define in Redis a threshold based on number of requests in every instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several experiments, i find a solution. The threshold selected on the basis of the response time. As presented in below Figure, the response time significantly increased in case of Request Rate >  20000.

[image]

My machine has the following configuration:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit
- Intel® CoreTM i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4
- 7,7 GiB RAM